# Change TYPO3 TCEFORM header_layout and header for a special plugin type

Tags: typo3, typoscript

In know it is possible to change configurations for the header_layout and header for every Ctype. For example for textmedia it would be:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.types.textmedia.disabled = 1
```

This is documented here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html

But what if i want to configure the header_layout for a special plugin? The Ctype for plugins are always of type list.
Is it also possible to differentiate between the list_types? Like this?

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.types.news_pi1.disabled = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible since you can only configure one field to be the "record type" field, which is "CType" in tt_content.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Ctrl/Index.html#type

You can only use `TCEFORM.tt_content.header_layout.types.list.disabled = 1` to disable this field for all plugins.

So make this work only for one plugin you'll have to create a new CType for it or maybe you override the whole header_layout field to make it become a type of "user" so you can setup the field visiblity yourself in a PHP function:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/User.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's the answer I suspected. Too bad that it is not possible to configure tx_news list and tx_news detail diferently.